# Como ligar um bit em um número?

Tags: c, c++, operadores, bit

Tem situações que usamos números para carregar *flags*, ou seja, cada bit, ou conjunto de bits, querem dizer alguma coisa específico de forma booleana. Ou precisamos manipular alguns dados de acordo com seus bits, talvez tenha a ver com cores ou algo que os bits individualmente acabam tendo um significado especial.

Em casos assim qual a forma mais simples de ligar um bit específico sabendo em que posição ele deve estar? E como desligá-lo ou inverter seu valor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para manipular bits o mais comum é usar os operadores de `|` (`or`), `&` (`and`) E `^` (`xor`), com apoio do `~` (complemento). O operador de *shift* ou deslocamento de bits costuma ser importante para chegar no bit desejado se o que você sabe é a posição dele. Esses operadores costumam estar presentes na maioria das linguagens com a mesma semântica, portanto tudo o que funciona aqui, deve funciona para outras linguagens. Diversas perguntas falam sobre isso:

- [Bit array in c duvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127460/101)
- [Para que servem os operadores | & << >>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101)
- [Qual a função dos operadores <<, >> e >>> no Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7889/101)
- [Para que serve o operador ~ (til) no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77924/101)
- [Como funciona o deslocamento de bits em C/C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10174/101)
- [Como manipular bit a bit um inteiro em c ou ccs?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136180/101)
- [Como funcionam os operadores de bit?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91049/101)
- [Operador " | " em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34292/101)
- [Teste de paridade em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124964/101)

Exemplos de *set*, *reset*, *toggle* e *test*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int posicao = 6; //posicao do bit (equivale ao 64)
    int valor = 0;
    valor |= 1 << posicao; //ligando o bit
    printf("Ligou o bit: %d\n", valor);
    int resultado = (valor >> posicao) & 1; //verificando valor do bit
    printf("O bit está: %d\n", resultado);
    valor &= ~(1 << posicao); //limpando o bit
    printf("Desligou o bit: %d\n", valor);
    resultado = (valor >> posicao) & 1; //verificando valor do bit
    printf("O bit está: %d\n", resultado);
    valor ^= 1 << posicao; //invertendo um bit
    printf("Inverteu o bit: %d\n", valor);
    valor |= 16; //ligando o bit pelo seu valor
    printf("Ligou o 4. bit: %d\n", valor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IY7xxq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/leuaosbb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/Bit.c).

É comum que algumas pessoas criem funções que façam exatamente isso para ser mais fácil de usar e lembrar.

Answer (score -2):

Seguem algumas funções que podem ajudar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

/**
 * Seta o valor de 1 bit em um numero.
 *
 * @param numero O numero que vai ser alterado.
 * @param pos A posicao do bit dentro do numero. O valor zero eh o bit mais da direita, o valor 31 eh o bit mais da esquerda.
 * @param valor O valor a ser setado no bit, deve ser Um ou Zero (estamos alterando apenas 1 bit)
 *
 * @return o numero alterado.
 **/
int setBit(unsigned int numero, int pos, int valor) {
    // mascara para ser posicionada na posicao pos.
    int mask = 1;

    // para garantir que valor so vai ter o valor zero ou um,
    // pega so o bit mais a direita dele.
    valor = valor & 1;

    // desloca valor para a esquerda, na posicao desejada.
    valor = valor << pos;

    // desloca mascara para a esquerda, na posicao desejada.
    mask = mask << pos;

    // seta o valor na posicao 
    numero = (numero & ~mask) | (valor);

    return numero;
}

/**
 * Seta o valor de 1 bit em um numero para 1.
 *
 * @param numero O numero que vai ser alterado.
 * @param pos A posicao do bit dentro do numero. O valor zero eh o bit mais da direita, o valor 31 eh o bit mais da esquerda.
 *
 * @return o numero alterado.
 **/
int ligaBit(unsigned int numero, int pos) {
    // mascara para ser posicionada na posicao pos.
    int mask = 1;

    // desloca mascara para a esquerda, na posicao desejada.
    mask = mask << pos;

    // seta o valor na posicao 
    numero = numero | mask;

    return numero;
}

/**
 * Seta o valor de 1 bit em um numero para 0.
 *
 * @param numero O numero que vai ser alterado.
 * @param pos A posicao do bit dentro do numero. O valor zero eh o bit mais da direita, o valor 31 eh o bit mais da esquerda.
 *
 * @return o numero alterado.
 **/
int desligaBit(unsigned int numero, int pos) {
    // mascara para ser posicionada na posicao pos.
    int mask = 1;

    // desloca mascara para a esquerda, na posicao desejada.
    mask = mask << pos;

    // seta o valor na posicao 
    numero = numero & ~mask;

    return numero;
}

int main() {
    int num = 0;

    printf("Testando setBit:\n");
    num = setBit(num, 1, 1);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);
    num = setBit(num, 2, 1);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);
    num = setBit(num, 3, 1);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);
    num = setBit(num, 3, 0);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);

    printf("Testando ligaBit e desligaBit:\n");
    num = 0;
    num = ligaBit(num, 1);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);
    num = ligaBit(num, 2);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);
    num = ligaBit(num, 3);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);
    num = desligaBit(num, 3);
    printf("num: %d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```