# MOD em assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, 8086

Preciso fazer uma comparação para verificar se o número X é PAR ou IMPAR.

- Armazeno o número no registrador AX.

Como eu faço para saber que o conteúdo de AX é par ou impar?

Obs: Armazeno um número de 1 até 99.

Comment: Qual arquitetura? x86?

Comment: Faz 25 anos que não mexo nisto, mas é só usar um `AND` e pegar o bit menos significativo com `SHR`. Só esse bit importa, se é 0 é par, se é 1 é impar. Em C: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tem muitas formas de saber se o numero é par ou impar em assembly, uma delas é trantando o numero em base2 (binario), quando o numero é par ele em binario termina em 0 e impar em 1, veja alguns exemplos

```
9 = 1001 (impar)
10 = 1010 (par)
11 = 1011 (impar)
56 = 111000 (par)
75 = 1001011 (impar)
65535 = 1111111111111111 (impar)
```

beleza agora como podemos ler apenas esse ultimo bit? para isso usamos a logica AND, na logica and apenas se ambos os bits forem verdadeiros ou seja 1 o retorno sera 1 caso contrario sera 0, nesse caso podemos simplesmente pegar o numero e fazer a operação and com o numero 1, se nessa operação retornar 1 quer dizer que o numero é impar ja que os dois bits é 1 que por sua vez vai retornar 1, se retornar 0 o numero é par, exemplo o numero 10

```
1010 = 10
0001 = 1
----
0000 = 0
```

outro exemplo com o numero 11

```
1011 = 11
0001 = 1
----
0001 = 1
```

como o resultado da operação é 0 podemos simplemente usar a instrução jz para pular para uma parte caso seja zero (par) ou jnz para pular caso seja diferente de 0 (impar)

```
mov ax,97
and ax,1
jz par
; aqui é impar

par:
; aqui é par
```

outra forma é pela divisão por 2, quando se divide um numero o resto é armazenado no registrador dx, então se o dx for o numero 0 é par ja que divisão por 2 em numeros par não tem resto, se for diferente de 0 ou seja 1 então é impar

```
mov ax,99
mov bx,2
idiv ax,bx
cmp dx,0
je par

par:
```

tem outras formas alem das citadas ^^

Comment: Me ajudou bastante, valeu! :)