# O que é um valor absoluto?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, matemática

Vendo a documentação do MySQL é possível encontrar a função matemática [ABS(x)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs), a qual diz retornar o **valor absoluto de x**.

```
mysql> SELECT ABS(2);
        -> 2
mysql> SELECT ABS(-32);
        -> 32
```

O que exatamente é esse valor absoluto e como ele funciona?

Comment: Um exemplo pratico de uso , um relatório previsto x realizado , queremos ordenar as maiores diferenças fazemos ORDER BY ABS(PREVISTO-REALIZADO) DESC , assim as maiores diferenças independente do sinal.

Comment: Pouco depois .... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/568694/como-posso-selecionar-registros-de-uma-tabela-olhando-para-uma-coluna-que-mais-s

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vou explicar um pouco do conceito matemático da função [ABS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs), pois acredito eu que é o que você deseja compreender, e é o que faz parte do escopo do site.

---

### ABS() - retorna o valor absoluto de um dado número

O que é um valor absoluto essa [pequena explicação](https://conceitos.com/valor-absoluto/) já da uma introdução:

> O valor absoluto de qualquer número se refere a sua magnitude e não ao sinal que pode ter, seja ele positivo ou negativo ...  Em termos matemáticos, o valor absoluto é uma operação que permite qualquer número tornar-se positivo.

Por isso que quando é utilizado essa função ABS ( ***ABS**olute value*, em inglês), como você citou:

```
mysql> SELECT ABS(2);
            -> 2
mysql> SELECT ABS(-32);
            -> 32
```

Irá retornar, respectivamente, os valores `2` e `32`. Basicamente sempre retornará o valor positivo, independente de qual número é X.

---

Essa função `ABS()`, está intimamente relacionada ao conceito de módulo ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value),[2](https://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/matematica/modulo-ou-valor-absoluto-calculando-o-modulo.htm)). Na verdade, porque é mesma função só que com outro nome.

Lembra, a muito tempo quando você estudou na escola, e seu professor colocava entre as *"barrinhas"* o número para *"descobrir o módulo"* `|x|`:

`|4|=4` ou `|-3|=3`

Basicamente, é esse conceito de ter o valor não negativo de X, independentemente do seu sinal, só que aplicado em banco de dados.

> Portanto, **|x| = x, se x for um número positivo** e **|x| = -x, se x for um número negativo**....

---

Alguns outros exemplos de saídas usando `ABS()`:

```
SELECT ABS(3);
      -> 3
SELECT ABS(-7);
      -> 7
SELECT ABS(0);
      -> 0
SELECT ABS(-1);
      -> 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Esta função está em todas as bibliotecas padrão das linguagens de programação e outras tecnologias que façam cálculos matemáticos.

Ela retorna sempre o valor positivo do número informado, ou seja, se for um positivo retorna ele mesmo, se for o negativo informa o número sem sinal. Ele é útil quando o sinal não é importante e sim o valor absoluto.

Em geral é uma operação muito barata porque é só [zerar um bit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101) do número. Uma implementação ingênua verificaria se o valor é negativo e multiplicaria por -1 para eliminar o sinal, mas isso é custoso e desnecessário.

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Para um número de ponto flutuante é zerar um bit. Números inteiros normalmente são representados em complemento de 2, a operação de negação é ligeiramente diferente.

Comment: Tem alguma referência sobre isso?

Comment: [Complemento de 2 na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_para_dois). Com 4 bits, +3 é representado como `0011` e -3 como `1101`

Comment: Sobre x86: http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf ; esse link abre uma página com um pdf embutido, enfim. Capítulo 4.2.1.2, _Signed Integers_: _All operations on signed 
integers assume a two's complement representation_

Comment: No caso, inverter e incrementar. +6 -> `0110`, -6 -> `1010`; `~+6 => 1001`; `inc(~+6) => inc(1001) => 1010`. Em termos de profundidade de portas lógicas, é muita pouca coisa que muda.

Answer (score 8):

Em matemática, *valor absoluto* é a distância em que um número está a partir do 0:

```
R = {...-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3...}
         |_______|________|
                 3
```

O -3 está a "3 casas" do zero, assim como o +3. Logo, o *valor absoluto* de ambos é 3.

O *valor absoluto* sempre retorna um número positivo, isso porque é ignorado o sinal negativo, se houver.

Em programação, quando há possibilidade de um número vir negativo mas você só quer saber seu valor absoluto, você então usa a respectiva função ou o método para isso.