# Identificar vários números numa variável

Tags: c++, variáveis

> Crie um programa que dado um conjunto de temperaturas de 8 cidades portuguesas, identificadas por um  n.º de ordem, **indique  quais  as  que  têm  temperatura  superior  à média do país.**

O meu problema está em identificar essas cidades através do seu número...

É possível identificar esse número de ordem através de uma só variável?

Por exemplo, a pessoa escreve o nº de ordem (que corresponde a uma cidade)
e no ecrã aparece os números de ordem se a temperatura da cidade for mais alta que a media do pais.

Só tenho isto

```
//var
float temperatura;
int nordem,i;


//codigo
for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
{
    cout<<"Introduza o nº de ordem: ";
    cin>>nordem;

    cout<<"Introduza a temperatura dessa cidade: ";
    cin>>temperatura;

        if(temperatura>16){
        nordem
    }

}cout<<"As seguintes cidades estão acima da média: "<<nordem<<"\n";

system("pause");
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *Array*

Não é possível guardar vários valores em uma variável escalar como deseja. É possível guardar em uma variável multi valorada. Um vetor é o tipo mais óbvio para fazer isso. Um vetor pode ser guardado em uma só variável, mas só pode guardar vários valores nele porque ele é composto por várias variáveis.

E sim, cada elemento do vetor é um variável individual. Então não há a menor chance de guardar tudo em uma só a não ser com algum truque possível se tiver algumas restrições.

Se optar por um vetor basta adicionar o número de ordem sempre que atender a condição e depois navegue pelo vetor em um laço posterior.

## Booleano

Na verdade pode fazer um vetor com um elemento para cada cidade, aí só guarda se a cidade atende o filtro ou não. Ou seja é uma operação booleana.

Aí dá para usar um truque e até usar uma variável. Se você garante que terá no máximo 8 cidades pode criar uma variável do tipo `char` (com um `unsigned int` é possível até 32 cidades, na maioria das arquiteturas). Aí você guarda se a cidade atende ao critério apenas com um bit.

Então a posição do bit é a posição do índice do que seria seu vetor e o bit ali indica se aquela cidade tem temperatura acima da média ou não.

Claro que isso só funciona se as cidades tiverem o número de ordem em sequência, de preferência de 0 a 7, mas dá para fazer mesmo começando de um número maior. Também seria possível se puder normalizar para uma sequência através da matemática.

Teria que usar o [operador de *bit*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101) para gerar os bits nos lugares corretos.

## *String*

Ainda tem a opção de fazer uma *string* com todos os valores separados por algum caractere ou com tamanho fixo. Tecnicamente ainda é só um valor, mas você dará uma semântica para esse valor que se comportará como se fossem vários. Acho gambiarra demais e principalmente nesse caso não vejo necessidade.