# C++ - Setar e remover bits específicos de um único

Tags: c++, bitwise

Estou desenvolvendo um emulador de Gameboy e uma das tarefas são setar os sinalizadores depois de cada instrução:

```
    ... 

    //Representa pares de registradores do gameboy
    union RegPair {

        std::uint16_t reg;
        struct pair
        {
            std::uint8_t lo;
            std::uint8_t hi;
        }p;

    };

    struct Registers{

        RegPair AF, BC, DE, HL;
        std::uint16_t SP, PC;

    };

    ...
```

Conjunto de flags do Gameboy

```
...

//Define as flags do processador
#define FLAG_ZERO_FLAG      7
#define FLAG_SUBSTRCAT_FLAG 6
#define FLAG_HALF_CARRY     5
#define FLAG_CARRY_FLAG     4
#define FLAG_NONE           0

...
```

Inicialização dos registradores:

```
    ...

    reg.AF.reg = 0x01B0;
    reg.BC.reg = 0x0013;
    reg.DE.reg = 0x00D8;
    reg.HL.reg = 0x014D;
    reg.SP = 0xFFFE;
    reg.PC = 0x0000;    //Ponto de entrada também pode ser 0x100

        ...
```

Vou usar o exemplo do opcode `0xD` que manda Decrementar o registrador C, tabela de opcodes pode ser encontrada [aqui](http://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html):

```
void CPU::DEC8(std::uint8_t& target, int cyclesToUpdate)
{
    cycles += cyclesToUpdate;
    target--;

    if (target == 0) {
        wxLogDebug("ZERO FLAG OCORREU");
        reg.AF.p.lo |= FLAG_ZERO_FLAG;
    }

    reg.PC++;

}
```

Acontece que se não ocorrer uma zero flag tenho que resetar especificamente a flag zero, e também pode ocorrer de adicionar a half carry flag, e se não ocorrer resetar a posição dela, eu achei essa resposta no [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/7878808) mas achei meio confusa, por exemplo, quando se passa um parâmetro para fstream:

```
("filename", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary)
```

Parece ser algo mais simples do que a maneira que esta na resposta.

Comment: Algo assim? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101

Comment: `FLAG_ZERO_FLAG` é `7` que corresponde a `111` em binário logo ao fazer `reg.AF.p.lo |= FLAG_ZERO_FLAG;` está a por os ultimos 3 bits a 1. Se os quisesse por a zero bastaria fazer `and` binário com a mascara invertida: `reg.AF.p.lo &= ~FLAG_ZERO_FLAG;`

Comment: @Isac mas desta forma afetaria as outras flags que estão neste registrador ou apenas esta flag em específico?

Comment: É apenas referente a esta flag.